# Specified Port is already in use - Visual Studio 2019 when multiple users run the application in RDP server

Tags: iis, localhost, visual-studio-2019, port, remote-server

[Debugging Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Phn.png)I have a remote server that has a development environment with visual studio 2019 and TFS. When a user runs the dot net web application, the url assigned will be localhost:50179. At the same time if another user runs the same application it show the specified port is already in use as the current url is also same (localhost:50179). When  I am using Local IIS(setting under Properties>web) there is no permission for the users other than administrator to create virtual directory. When I gave permission for the users , it says unable to start debugging as the server is not found with localhost.
So in short, Either I want to generate dynamic ports at run time without conflicting with multiple users or I want to run as Local IIS without error(Error attached as image). Please help. Thank you

I converted Web site to web application and also I gave full permission to users for IIS.

Comment: This has been known for decades. One of the developers has to edit the port number and then debug. There is no way to generate dynamic ports for IIS/IIS Express configuration.

Comment: I didn't see the image of the error message you attached, please re-edit your question to add detailed error information.

Comment: Can we use local IIS to run simultaneously?

Comment: I have uploaded the image

Answer (score 0):

Please check if VS is running as administrator, if not, try running as administrator.

Comment: If I run as administrator for normal users  does the tfs mapping folder change for normal users?

Comment: I don't know TFS very well, this is the advice I gave after seeing your error image.